# iPhone 5s/ iCloud info

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to see the settings of my iPhone without actually looking at the phone? For example on a computer logged into the AppleID or iCloud? I need to make sure the "Find my iPhone" info is turned on on my daughter's iPhone.

I was using the app [xFi Locator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funreality.software.nativefindmyiphone.lite&hl=de) to track her whereabouts and it was working fine until her data was turned off, because it had reached the limit. I've contacted xFi support and they had a list of items to look for, which were all set properly.  However, I think my daughter has turned this feature off.  Hence the question above.

Comment: Do you use [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) ? With Family sharing you can check the location of all family members from https://www.icloud.com/#find [At least you can if you are the 'primary' member, I'm not certain if you aren't, as I'm primary for my family]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if **find my iPhone** is turned on on a device, you can check the activation lock on icloud.com using this link: [icloud.com/activationlock](https://www.icloud.com/activationlock/)

You will need to have the IMEI or serial number of the device. Both can be find in the the settings app on the device, or at the back of the box that came along with the iPhone.